# Use one map in multiple layouts but at different scale in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts

In ArcGIS Pro I have created a map, I also have 3 layouts in the project and I want to use the same map in all of the layouts, but at different scales.

For example, one layout is an overview (1:250K), one is midrange (1:25K), and the other is detailed site map (1:1K), all use the same layers and symbology but each layout would have specific layers turned on or off, such as turning off a mapsheet grid on the detailed site layout but having it on for the overview.

I can get the same map into each layout but it seems to have a set scale at the map level that persists across all layouts, so the symbology does not adjust to suit the different layout scales.

Can this work this way or do I have to make a separate map for each layout and copy/paste the layers from one map to the others and then set each's scale differently?

Comment: Vote for it: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/locked-multiple-layouts-in-arcgis-pro/idi-p/924876  i'm waiting for a long time. It is frustrating if you are used it from qgis

Comment: Different scale, without differen symbology should work. You can also use scaled based symbolgy

Comment: Have you looked at map frame constraints which should take care of locking to a fixed scale? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/layouts/customizing-your-map-extent.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_0DC78E782CBF4416AA02462A2824DB25